# NSManaged object sometimes is null and causes crash

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am using coredata and often my app crashes because one of the properties of a managed object turn out null. For example when i set text of a `UILabel` to a text property of the managed object it displays `NULL`
To find the problem I overrode the setter which assigns the NSManagedObject to a instance variable. In the setter I use NSLog to print the object:
`NSLog(@"TSC: setting segment: %@", segment);`
its output:

```
2012-11-05 21:01:56.758 JetLagged[4505:907] TSC: setting segment: <Segment: 0x1d0ab790> (entity: Segment; id: 0x1d0a7f60 <x-coredata://BF6F2D98-0658-4005-8BEF-9FE6B398AF86/Segment/p8> ; data: {
arrivalDate = "2012-11-11 05:00:17 +0000";
arrivalLeg = "0x1d0abba0 <x-coredata://BF6F2D98-0658-4005-8BEF-9FE6B398AF86/IteneryLeg/p11>";
departureDate = "2012-11-10 19:00:17 +0000";
departureLeg = "0x1d0abba0 <x-coredata://BF6F2D98-0658-4005-8BEF-9FE6B398AF86/IteneryLeg/p11>";
iteneryLegs =     (
    "0x1d0abba0 <x-coredata://BF6F2D98-0658-4005-8BEF-9FE6B398AF86/IteneryLeg/p11>"
);
trip = "0x1c58add0 <x-coredata://BF6F2D98-0658-4005-8BEF-9FE6B398AF86/Trip/p5>";
})
```

All looks fine, however app still displayes null in some places or crashes. I catch the problem I added some NSAsserts and when I ran the code below in the same run as the output above it failed the assertion. Here is the assert code (segmentToCheck is segment from above).

```
    NSSet *legs = [segmentToCheck valueForKey:@"iteneryLegs"];
    NSAssert([legs count] != 0, @"Error: nolegs %@", legs);
```

its output:

```
2012-11-05 21:01:56.763 JetLagged[4505:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error: nolegs (null)'
```

When i run the app again (without any data modification) it works fine. Any idea what it might be?

Comment: Can you post the whole class code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo: `@"itineryLegs"` instead of `@"iteneryLegs"`.